# Why spring mvc convert object to json remove the is-(prefix) for boolean property automatically

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I use spring mvc 4.0.2. I defined a class with several boolean properties, such as `isSoldout`, `autoMergeWhileChoose` . The simplified code as

```
public class Dish implements Serializable{
    private boolean autoMergeWhileChoose = true;
    private boolean isNew = false;
    private boolean isSpecial = false;
    private boolean isSoldOut = false;
    ......
}
```

I get the json from client side. I found the properties with `is-` prefix have been removed the `is-`. For example, `isSoldOut` changes to `soldOut`. But the other boolean properties without prefix is- don't change. I show a part of the json here

```
{
    ...
    "autoMergeWhileChoose" : true,
    "new" : false,
    "soldOut" : false,
    "special" : false
    ...
}
```

You can find the first `autoMergeWhileChoose` does not change, but the following three are changed without the prefix `is-`.

The convertor is `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, and the config file is

```
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
      <beans:list>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
          <beans:property name="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
        </beans:bean>
      </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>
```

Are there some settings to deal with it?

Comment: Please post the object where you define the properties

Comment: @SongtaoLou I think you can use `@JsonProperty("isSoldout")` above field/getter in your class. Other option is to change getter name to something like `isIsSoldout` but it will look ugly.

Comment: Workaround please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is

Comment: @varren thank you , I feel you idea would be worked. I will try it now.

Comment: @varren The result changed to `isSoldout` now, but `soldout` is still existing. now both of them have same value. but it is not serious. Thank you