# can't response 'isOk' field in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i'm creating CreateOrUpdateProduct API use Spring boot. i want to return to consumer two fields ('message & isOk'). But when i exec this API, i received ('message & ok') fields. what's happened? please expand me. thanks advance!

this is my function

```
public ResponseBase CreateOrUpdateProduct(Product product) {

        ....
        return responseBase;
    }
```

```
public class ResponseBase {
boolean isOk;
public boolean isOk() {
    return isOk;
}
public void setOk(boolean isOk) {
    this.isOk = isOk;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
String message;
}
```

i received

```
{
  "message":null,
  "ok": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is here: [Jackson renames boolean field by removing is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is)

Jackson (serializer) sees "isOk" as a get method of a boolean variable named "ok". This is a common naming pattern developers use on get methods for boolean variables.

**EDIT:**

You shouldn't set the name of your method to "getIsOk", because that doesn't follow the naming convention of get method for boolean variables. This is not a very good solution, but it'll work.

Jackson provides an annotation to you that set the name of the serialized variable:

```
@JsonProperty(value="isOk")
public boolean isOk() {
  return isOk;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rename your getter to `getIsOk()`.

It will return the expected answer :

```
{
  "message":null,
  "isOk": true
}
```