# Don't work convert type boolean from Json with Srping Boot 2.x

Tags: json, spring-boot, boolean, dto

I use Spring Boot 2.x and maven

- pom.xml

```xml
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

- json, That is sending.

```
{
  "name": "fan",

  "isCar": true,

  "year": 2020,

  "character": "W",

  "cost": 10,

  "status": "OPEN"
}
```

- a part of DTO

```java
public abstract class DifferentTypesDtoFour extends DifferentTypesDtoTwo {

    private Integer year;

    private boolean isCar;

    public DifferentTypesDtoFour() {
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean isCar() {
        return isCar;
    }

    public void setCar(boolean car) {
        isCar = car;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        DifferentTypesDtoFour that = (DifferentTypesDtoFour) o;
        return isCar == that.isCar &&
                Objects.equals(year, that.year);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), year, isCar);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\n" + "DifferentTypesDtoFour{" +
                "year=" + year +
                ", isCar=" + isCar +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I can 't understand the origin of this problem.

When the request comes to the rest controller , the dto receives the converted data.

Almost data is converted the correct, but the field 
**isCar = false...**

Why ?

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

**Update**

I used the following:

```java
public abstract class DifferentTypesDtoFour extends DifferentTypesDtoTwo {

    private Integer year;

    private boolean isCar;

    public DifferentTypesDtoFour() {
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "isCar")
    public boolean isCar() {
        return isCar;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "isCar")
    public void setCar(boolean car) {
        isCar = car;
    }
...

}
```

The type boolean saved  indeed, but when the data is back to rest-controller, the client receives a response and the type boolean again don't transform  correct.

Comment: Check the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is

Comment: I rolled back the last edit. Please don't edit solutions into the question. Solutions are only to be given in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is with your *setter* of `isCar` field - the setter method's name should be `setIsCar` instead of `setCar` so that the request json's `isCar` value can be mapped into your model's `isCar` property,

```
public void setIsCar(boolean isCar) {
    this.isCar = isCar;
}
```

**Edit 1...**
As @Gimby mentioned that your `getter` name should be `isIsCar`, it will not affect while getting HTTP request but it will eventually look unmatched `getter` for that field - and you may consider re-naming your variable to avoid such typo issues.

**Edit 2...** One of the ways to get rid of the issue is using [@JsonProperty](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#property-naming) without renaming methods as mentioned by @GabLeg,

```
@JsonProperty(value="isCar")
public void setCar(boolean car) {
    this.isCar = car;
}
```

Comment: the getter is also wrong in the same way, should then get the funky name isIsCar().

Comment: One way to get rid of the funky name like `isIsCar()` is to add the annotation `@JsonProperty("isCar")`.