# Boolean field in entity changes name in JSON

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, dao, lombok

Something curious is happening in my application and I would like to know the reason.

I have a resource that is constructed with a backend service in my Spring server, and when the JSON arrives at the front end one of the property names is different. I have followed with breakpoints the entire construction of the resource and at no point before returning the query does the property name ever change from `isHiddenOnQuote` - as you probably suspect, it's defined as a boolean in the object model. My database stores the value as a 1 or 0.

When the JSON is received by my front end, the property name changes to `hiddenOnQuote` - the "is" magically drops off. Strange as well, is the fact that I have other boolean fields in the JSON that don't change; they retain their "is"ness.

Here is a snippet from the model. Note that none of these properties exist in the superclass, BaseEntity.

```
package com.company.app.model.sales;

import com.company.app.model.BaseEntity;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@SQLDelete(sql =
        "UPDATE product_option_category " +
                "SET is_deleted = true " +
                "WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")

public class ProductOptionCategory extends BaseEntity {
    private String categoryName;

    private int optionLimit;

    private int mnSegment;

    private boolean isBitwise;

    private boolean areOptionsRepeatable = false;

    private boolean isHiddenOnQuote = false;

    public boolean getIsBitwise() {
        return isBitwise;
    }
}
```

Is this a Lombok thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you may have hit upon a bug if isBitwise works well but not isHiddenOnQuote.

Also, noticed that you are not using the @Getter etc annotations from Lombok. Perhaps you can try using the following annotations to force the correct name:

`@get:JsonProperty("isHiddenOnQuote")`

`@param:JsonProperty("isHiddenOnQuote")`

I got this from this answer on Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55100741/4402505

EDIT: Fixed the property name.

Comment: awesome! Thank you

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, it looks like it wasn't a bug. I apologize, I had a getter function for the isBitwise field, I didn't include it because it didn't seem relevant. Now I understand Jackson would have used the method for serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lombok generate for primitive boolean variable method with prefix "is" according to Java naming convention ([https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs2103/AY1617S1/contents/coding-standards-java.html](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Ecs2103/AY1617S1/contents/coding-standards-java.html)).
We can annotate that field with `@Getter`:

```
@Getter
private boolean running;
```

And Lombok will use its annotation processor to generate an `isRunning()` method in the class.

Sometimes, there can be conflicts.
Let's say that we need to have the following lines in the same class:

```
@Getter
public boolean running = true;

@Getter
public boolean isRunning = false;
```

There are many reasons we should avoid a confusing naming convention like this. One of them is that it creates a conflict for Lombok.

Using Lombok's convention, these two fields would have the same accessor method name: `isRunning`. But having two methods with the same name in the same class will create a compiler error.

Lombok solves this by creating only one accessor method and, in this case, pointing it at running, based on field declaration order.