# object name attribute changes when response from controller is generated (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I work on a spring boot project. And I create a class to represent the request body for another service. Before I use this class I want to check first, if the structure is correct. So I create a simple controller to return an object from this class.

here my `LocationConstraint` class:

```
public class LocationConstraint {
    boolean isRequired;
    boolean suggestLocation;
    List<Location> locations;
}
```

and this is the response when I check using Postman
[response on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtg8d.png)

As you can see, attribute name change from `isRequired` to be `required`. Why did this happen?

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is

Comment: thanks @Arnaud , it works as I expect