# IntelliJ / Lombok messing around with "is" prefix and removing it

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, getter-setter, lombok

I have no idea what is happening but for some reason the is prefix from my property is being removed.

I have even removed the annotations from Lombok and manually created the getters and setters but for some reason, I get this weird error.

I have a prop called isAuthenticated, that must return to the browser, for some reason, I am getting authenticated.

Here is the code:
//The end point in the API:
@GetMapping("/auth")
public EmployeeState getEmployeeState(HttpServletRequest request) {
return employeeService.getEmployeeState(request.getSession());
}

The Service method:

```
public EmployeeState getEmployeeState(HttpSession session) {

        EmployeeState employeeState = new EmployeeState();
        employeeState.setIsAuthenticated(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());

        if (employeeState.isAuthenticated()){
            if (session.getAttribute("employeeNumber") != null){
                Employee employee = employeeRepository.getEmployeeByEmployeeNumber(session.getAttribute("employeeNumber").toString()).get();
                employeeState.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
                employeeState.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
                employeeState.setEmployeeNumber(employee.getEmployeeNumber());
            }
        }

        return employeeState;
    }
```

This is the model, the response is supposed to return:

```
public class EmployeeState {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private boolean isAuthenticated;

    public EmployeeState(){

    }

    public EmployeeState(String firstName, String lastName, String employeeNumber, boolean isAuthenticated) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
        this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return isAuthenticated;
    }

    public void setIsAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
        isAuthenticated = authenticated;
    }
}
```

Result in the browser:

[image: Why is isAuthenticated returning as authenticated?]

Edit 1:

I tried to add the @JsonProperty annotation, and now I get two properties:

```
public class EmployeeState {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String employeeNumber;

    @JsonProperty(value = "isAuthenticated")
    private boolean isAuthenticated;

    public EmployeeState(){

    }

    public EmployeeState(String firstName, String lastName, String employeeNumber, boolean isAuthenticated) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
        this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return isAuthenticated;
    }

    public void setIsAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
        isAuthenticated = authenticated;
    }
}
```

Now there are two properties:

[image: Now it shows two properties]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson renames primitive boolean field by removing 'is'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is)

Comment: Thank you, I just tried that, although it works, but now it sends two properties. I am going to update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Java Bean naming convention for your getter method would be `isIsAuthenticated`. Jackson tries to use the Java bean convention, and in this case, your class doesn't conform to it. You can try adding the `@JsonProperty(value = "isAuthenticated")` annotation on the `isAuthenticated` method directly. Additionally, to prevent any duplicate fields in the JSON, you could then add `@JsonIgnore` on the `isAuthenticated` field, if you don't need to serialize that field from JSON.

Small explanation why you have 2 fields in JSON now:

The correct property name, that Jackson derives from your `isAuthenticated()` method is `authenticated`. The property name is derived such that the getter prefix (which is `is` for boolean methods) is removed and the following letter converted to lower case). That's why you see the JSON property `authenticated`.

Additionally Jackson sees your `isAuthenticated` field, and creates a JSON property for it as well, which is then named `isAuthenticated`. By adding the `@JsonProperty` annotation on the field itself, nothing changes for Jackson, because for Jackson, the `isAuthenticated()` method has no relation at all to the field and setter method and thus they are treated as two different JSON properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct experience.

**boolean** as a primitive data type is handled in a way where the "is" keyword is removed while serializing/deserializing.

So to avoid the confusion:

1. we can use non-primitive data type **Boolean**.
2. can add an extra "**is**" before the boolean field name.
3. add @JsonProperty("isField") on top of the boolean field.