# JsonProperty and Field Annotation not working together in Java Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jackson

I am working on a model that involves the data type `boolean`, so the issue with `Jackson` is that if I put in `isValid` it will auto convert to `valid` in the schema. However this model schema is in need to store into MongoDB, and I want `isValid` to be the field, not `valid`.

So I searched around and I read that `@Field("isValid")` should solve the issue, however it is not and it is causing `@JsonProperty("isValid")` not working as well.

What happened here is when I put only `@JsonProperty("isValid")`, it can be serialized and deserialized as `isValid` perfectly, however when I try to insert into MongoDB, the field change into `valid` instead of `isValid`.

Here are my code for the POJO:

```
@Data
@ToString
public class Response {
    private String duration;

    private String time;

    @JsonProperty("isValid")
    @Field("isValid")
    private boolean isValid;
}
```

This is what I want inside the MongoDB:

```
{
   "duration": "313610236",
   "isValid": false,
   "time": "1658304521794"
}
```

However now I have:

```
{
   "duration": "313610236",
   "valid": false,
   "time": "1658304521794"
}
```

How can I achieve both function where I get to deserialize and serialize as `isValid` but also saved as `isValid` in terms of field into the MongoDB?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"valid"}) // Prevents serialization
@Data
@ToString
public class Response {
    private String duration;

    private String time;

    @JsonProperty("isValid")
    private boolean isValid;
}
```

Found a link that might be helpful for you:
[Jackson renames primitive boolean field by removing 'is'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is)