# Java object to JSON conversion is giving extra attributes which is not present in java builder class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I am working on Java Object to JSON conversion using ObjectMapper but it is giving extra attribute which is not present in my java class.

Below is the Java Object Builder class.

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = OrderSummary.Builder.class)
public class OrderSummary extends ABC {

    @JsonProperty("orderCode")
    private String orderCode;

    @JsonProperty("transactionAmount")
    private long transactionAmount;

    @JsonProperty("transactionCurrency")
    private String transactionCurrency;

    @JsonProperty("isPayout")
    private boolean isPayout;

    private OrderSummary(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        orderCode = builder.orderCode;
        transactionAmount = builder.transactionAmount;
        transactionCurrency = builder.transactionCurrency;
        isPayout = builder.isPayout;
    }
    public static Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public String getOrderCode() {
        return orderCode;
    }
    public long getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
    }
    public String getTransactionCurrency() {
        return transactionCurrency;
    }
    public boolean isPayout() {
        return isPayout;
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static final class Builder extends ABC.Builder<Builder> {

        private String orderCode;

        private long transactionAmount;

        private String transactionCurrency;

        private boolean isPayout;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder withOrderCode(String val) {
            orderCode = val;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withTransactionAmount(long val) {
            transactionAmount = val;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withTransactionCurrency(String val) {
            transactionCurrency = val;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder withIsPayout(boolean val) {
            isPayout = val;
            return this;
        }
        public OrderSummary build() {
            return new OrderSummary(this);
        }
        @Override
        protected Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

It extends 1 class which has only 2 attributes

1. transaction code
2. unique identifier

But when I have using Object Mapper object to convert to json getting below json

```
{
              "payout": false,
              "transactionCode": "ABCJD",
              "uniqueIdentifier": 78632,
              "orderCode": "12345",
              "transactionAmount": 1200,
              "transactionCurrency": "EUR",
              "isPayout": false,
}
```

I am not sure how `"payout": false,` is added in json.

I tried converting another java object which does not have `boolean` it is working fine without any issue.

Can you please help me in how can I fix this conversion.

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the whole process that you are did, and how BUT.

some solution that could be

1. adding this annotation to serialized class

   `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"payout"})`
2. use google gson, it very efficient, very secure and very good serializer in all software engineering terms.