# boolean is set to false if it's not present in @RequestBody

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I've stumbled upon interesting case and I'm not sure how to resolve it. It's probably related to [JSON Post request for boolean field sends false by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913955/json-post-request-for-boolean-field-sends-false-by-default) but advices from that article didn't help.

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class ReqBody {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{10}$")
    private String phone;
    //other fields
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty(value = "create_anonymous_account")
    private Boolean createAnonymousAccount = null;
    //constructors, getters and setters
    public Boolean getCreateAnonymousAccount() {
        return createAnonymousAccount;
    }

    public void setCreateAnonymousAccount(Boolean createAnonymousAccount) {
        this.createAnonymousAccount = createAnonymousAccount;
    }
}
```

I also have endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MyOutput> test(
            @ApiParam(value = "information", required = true) @RequestBody ReqBody input
    ) {
//do something
}
```

problem is when I send my request body as:

```
{
"phone": "0000000006",
 "create_anonymous_account": null
}
```

or just like

```
{
"phone": "0000000006"
}
```

it sets createAnonymousAccount to false.

I have checked, and it correctly recognises `"create_anonymous_account": true`

Is there any way to "force" null value in boolean field?

I really need to know if it was sent or no, and not to have default value.

Comment: You annotated the field with `@NotNull` -> seems like a copy-paste-error / a typo?

Comment: It's strange to annotate the field with `@NotNull` and to initialize it with `createAnonymousAccount = null`

Comment: I wanted it not to be null (so it won't pass validation if not set), but make it null by defalut (so that ```{"phone": "0000000006"}``` won't pass validation)

Comment: Whoever still looks how to pass optional parameters via `@RequestBody` (not just whole body optional), make sure your boolean field is declared `private Boolean` and not `private boolean` then it may have `null`/`true`/`false` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jackson annotation to ignore the null fields. If the Caller doesn't send createAnonymousAccount then it will be null.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ReqBody {
    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{10}$")
    private String phone;
    //other fields

    @JsonProperty(value = "create_anonymous_account")
    private Boolean createAnonymousAccount ;
}
```